# How to create table separate objects out of json using JSONATA

Tags: json, jsonata

I want to transform a given JSON structure into another json format using the JSONATA API.
Basically, I need to break the hierarchical structure into separate records.

Input JSON:

```
{
  "2022-09-22": [
    {
      "name": "modules/dynatrace",
      "count": 60
    },
    {
      "name": "modules/dynatrace/monitors/http-monitors/basic",
      "count": 4
    },
    {
      "name": "modules/splunk/hec-token",
      "count": 14
    },
    {
      "name": "modules/aws/lambda/logs_streaming_splunk",
      "count": 29
    }
  ]
}
```

Output:

```
[
{
"date" : "2022-09-22",
"name": "modules/dynatrace",
"count": 60
},
{
"date" : "2022-09-22",
"name": "modules/dynatrace/monitors/http-monitors/basic",
"count": 4
},
{
"date" : "2022-09-22",
"name": "modules/splunk/hec-token",
"count": 14
},
{
"date" : "2022-09-22",
"name": "modules/aws/lambda/logs_streaming_splunk",
"count": 29
}
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `$each` function to convert object into an array:

```
$each($$, function($entries, $date) {
  $entries.($merge([{ "date": $date }, $]))
})
```

Interactive link: https://stedi.link/ZBoBY2F

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am here trying to prepare list of objects for each object located in the deep like 'name' and 'count'. So for given input it should return 8 objects.

Comment: Sorry, not sure I follow. Would you mind providing a full example result you expect for the given input?

Comment: I have updated the output.

Comment: Right, I get it now - check this one out: https://stedi.link/ZBoBY2F

Comment: Thanks. I got one more question here to clear out my doubt.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73882914/how-to-flatten-array-of-arrays-in-json-using-jsonata