# How to flatten array of arrays in json using jsonata

Tags: json, jsonata

I want to flatten an array of arrays in json data into array of objects.
I am giving input and expected output. I am not familiar with some flattening functions in jsonata and that's where I need help.

Input:

```
[
  [
    {
      "date": "2022-09-22",
      "name": "modules/dynatrace",
      "count": 60
    },
    {
      "date": "2022-09-22",
      "name": "modules/dynatrace/monitors/http-monitors/basic",
      "count": 4
    }
    ],
    [
    {
      "date": "2022-09-22",
      "name": "modules/splunk/hec-token",
      "count": 14
    },
    {
      "date": "2022-09-22",
      "name": "modules/aws/lambda/logs_streaming_splunk",
      "count": 29
    }
    ]
]
```

Output:

```
[
    {
      "date": "2022-09-22",
      "name": "modules/dynatrace",
      "count": 60
    },
    {
      "date": "2022-09-22",
      "name": "modules/dynatrace/monitors/http-monitors/basic",
      "count": 4
    },
    {
      "date": "2022-09-22",
      "name": "modules/splunk/hec-token",
      "count": 14
    },
    {
      "date": "2022-09-22",
      "name": "modules/aws/lambda/logs_streaming_splunk",
      "count": 29
    }
]
```

Comment: I believe this SO question provides some options: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49570172/jsonata-query-to-flatten-array-of-arrays

Answer (score 1):

I used below command as mention in the another ticket and it worked for me.|https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49570172/jsonata-query-to-flatten-array-of-arrays

```
$reduce($, $append)
```